# Http calls in Protractor - Failed: asynchronous script timeout: result was not received in 60 seconds

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm calling `http` in protractor e2e test. The API worked (I mean database was updated) but the assertion failed and returned this error:

> Failed: asynchronous script timeout: result was not received in 60 seconds

Here is my code:

```
it('Devrait modifier la durée avant connexion', function(){
  browser.executeAsyncScript(function(){
      $http = angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$http");
      $http({
          method: 'PUT',
          dataType: "json",
          url: 'http://localhost:3333/api/utilisateur/999999993?utilisateur_key=TESTKEY_3',
          data: {
              "session_timeout": "5"
          },
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
      }).then(
          function success(response) {
              console.log('response', response);
          },(function error(error,status){
              console.log('error', error)
          })
      );
  });
});
```

I increased the timeout in the config as below:

```
browser.driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(60000);
```

Comment: increase 'allScriptsTimeout: 60000' value in conf.js file

Comment: I"ve already tried that, but I've got the same error! thanks for responding

Comment: Why do you want to test this with Protractor? Is there a UI interaction? If so, why not split it up into a API test (without Protractor) and a UI test with Protractor and a mocking module. [ng-Apimock](https://github.com/mdasberg/ng-apimock) is a nice module for that. That will mock all data and speeds up the tests

Comment: thanks for responding! It's fixed after adding a callback into argument then call it after.